# Running through two list parallel in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi if I have two list

`x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
 y = [1, 2, 3]`

and I want to combine them and get similar combination of zip (`list(zip(x,y))`) using list comprehension? 
So the desired output I want is

`[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`

I tried

`[(alp, num) for alp in x for num in y]`
 
But in run two list in a nested way and I got output

`[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('c', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 3)]`

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: `for xval, yval in zip(x, y)`

Comment: `[i for i in zip(x,y)]`

Comment: [(n, m) for i, m in enumerate(x) for j, m in enumerate(y) if i==j]